# What is the syntax for Project Relative Path in Eclipse Resource Filter?

Tags: java, eclipse, google-app-engine, objectify, google-plugin-eclipse

I want to filter a source code directory from the Objectify 3.1 library I'm including in my Google App Engine project that uses the Google Plugin for Eclipse.  Most likely I imported their library incorrectly but I'd like to see if I can just "hide" this source directory from Eclipse so it doesn't try to compile it.

I'm trying to use the a Resource Filter.  The Project Relative Path seems most appropriate but I can't figure out the syntax.  Which way do slashes go?  Do I put a slash at the beginning?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The syntax that I found to work for the Project Relative Path was `lib/objectify-3.1/src/*` to hide the source code directory under the objectify-3.1 folder under lib.  No slash was required at the beginning and the slashes are `/` not `\`.

See screenshot for more context:

[image]

Comment: **IMPORTANT IMPORTANT IMPORTANT!** You *must* check the box for `All children (recursive)` as you have done, in order for the **Project Relative Path** option to exclude any relative folders at all! Otherwise it just doesn't work! I spent about 45 min trying to get it to exclude a folder nested 1 level deep and no matter what I did the **Project Relative Path** option would not work until I finally checked that box!

Comment: Eclipse Resource Filters are horrible. They are so hard to work with and make work. I couldn't get them to work just now until I just used Name filters and manually drilled down, applying "Include only" filters to one folder, then a folder inside that, then a folder inside that, etc, to get the effect I want by having multiple filters scattered all over the place.  NOTE: I recommend disabling the Indexer while setting up filters to try to keep your CPU below 100% so you can do anything at all. Once your filters are set up, turn the Indexer back on.